# Does the energy and/or mass of an electron change during the act of measurement and so the wavefunction collapse?

Tags: mass-energy, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

In the double-slit experiment, if we want to know which slit did the electron go through, we have to use a laser that gives an energy to the electron. Now, I have two questions: 
1. Does the energy of the electron increase after the measurement and then decrease to its initial energy after the measurement, OR it just increases without any subsequent decrease?
2. Has any experiment ever been done to measure any change of mass of the electron during its wavefunction collapse due to the act of measurement? If yes, what is the observation and if not, what is the expected result?

Comment: When Schrödinger devised a scheme to murder a cat, he does not care much about the changes in the weight of the cyanide.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I couldn't understand your answer. Does the mass of an electron increase, decrease or doesn't change when its wavefunction collapses (given experimental evidences, if any exists)? I cannot put your answer into any of the above-mentioned categories (i.e. increase, decrease, or no change).  Would you please clarify this more for me?

Answer (score 0):

The mass of the electron is the "length" of the (energy, momentum) four vector describing it, [see here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html), so it never changes. The length is called an invariant mass, it is invariant during Lorenz transformations, as is the whole quantum field theory modeling elementary (and complex) particle interactions, by construction.

In interactions, the collapse model is dated and really confusing. A Feynman diagram that can calculate the probability of interaction exists for all quantum mechanical proceses. These diagrams contain off mass shell lines with the quantum number of electrons, and within the mathematics, the mass changes according to the integral which gives the probability of finding the electron at (x,y,z,t).

Interactions depend on the boundary conditions, in [the double slit experiment, one electron at a time,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) one can see the accumulation of the probability. Each point is a measurement, and there is no collapse, just a footprint of each electron with the same energy impinging on two slits , the same boundary conditions.

If a laser or another method is used, boundary conditions change which means another probability distribution describes the experiment. See t[his simpler experiment](https://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html) then using lasers, which shows the effect of boundary conditions.

If the energy of the electrons, or as the last experiment shows the vector direction of the momentum changes, it is a different experiment, due to new boundary conditions.